# Javascript result to Prepared Statement

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page that populates a dropdown list dynamically from a database, then I have the dropdown list set up with an "onchange" event to call a Javascript to obtain the selected value.  How can I use the Javascript result to be placed in a WHERE clause of a SQL prepared statment?

The prepared statement I have set up in a JavaBean.

Comment: You do realize that javascript is executed by the browser, but your Java code is not, right? You can't execute a preparedstatement in javascript, that's Java code executing on the server.

Comment: Okay.  I am not a web guru.  Previously Unix background.  In that case basically how do I get the value selected from one dropdown list to be used in the WHERE clause of a Prepared Statement in a JavaBean?

Comment: Yeah... do you really expect people to repeat here what whole chapters of books are dedicated to explain? You have a unix background you say, imagine someone asking in a forum "can someone tell me how to compile my own kernel?". What do you do? Point them to a howto or go ahead and spend an hour typing up an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `form` for the dropdown and send the response from JSP to any Servlet or controller. From there get the dropdown value by

`request.getParameter("name")`.

Now you have dropdown value in servlet, from here you can set this value in any class.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on this please Deepak.  This is my first JSP project.  This is a stand alone JSP application and not part of a servlet.  Thanks

Comment: Request attributes **are not** request parameters.

Comment: Okay guys.  Thanks so far.  I am not a web guru.  Previously Unix background.  In that case basically how do I get the value selected from one dropdown list to be used in the WHERE clause of a Prepared Statement in a JavaBean?